# Nothing-but: singular or plural

Tags: idioms

1. Nothing but books and magazines pleases/please her.

What is the subject "Nothing" or "Books and magazines"? What should we use here singular or plural?

2. Nothing pleases/please her but books and magazines.

If change the position of "but", then would it change the grammar of sentence or it doesn't make any difference?

I have same confusion with "all but", "everything but", "anything but".

Answer (score 3):

"But" in your sentence is used as a preposition that means "except (for)" and "but books and magazines" is a prepositional phrases which doesn't have any influence on the singularity of a subject. If you omit it, the sentence is changed to:

> Nothing **pleases** her.

You can also rephrase the sentence to:

> Nothing **pleases** her but books and magazines.

It is grammatical for to please to agree with the singular "nothing" as nothing is singular.

When "nothing but" is replaced by "only" as in:

> Only books and magazines please her.

to please has to agree with the plural subjects.

Now, whether to use "pleases" or "please" in your sentence could be controversial and I don't think it is an easy issue to determine. However, grammatically and formally, using the singular agreement is right. Using "please" could be more informal or colloquial. It will largely depend on where you place the emphasis.

Comment: Is this applicable for "all but", "everything but", "anything but". You said "But" is used as preposition. But there is also a idiom "Nothing but". What if "but" is a part of idiom. [nothing but] [books and magazines please her].

Comment: Nothing but means "only" as a set phrase (idiom) because but means "except (for)". If you say "Only books and magazines please her", the verb has to agree with the plural subjects. However, i don't think it applies to nothing but. I will edit my post reflecting your concern.

Answer (score 0):

From all indefinite pronouns, only *both, few, many, others,* and *several* are plural.

As for *nothing*, according to the traditional rule, it is invariably treated as a singular, ***even when followed by an exception phrase containing a plural noun***:

> Nothing except your fears stands (not stand) in your way.
>
> Nothing but roses meets (not meet) the eye.

[The source](https://books.google.ru/books?id=BEHFyMCdwssC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=nothing+is+invariably+treated+as+a+singular,+even+when+followed+by+an+exception+phrase+containing+a+plural+noun&source=bl&ots=yroCeuyFQx&sig=HYcxBbflQxDpZ4lA65H-SFZkq4s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVlPmzkpHPAhXC1iwKHU4OAKsQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=nothing%20is%20invariably%20treated%20as%20a%20singular%2C%20even%20when%20followed%20by%20an%20exception%20phrase%20containing%20a%20plural%20noun&f=false):The American Heritage Book of English Usage.

BUT there are certain contexts in which *nothing but* sounds quite natural with a plural verb and should not be considered inappropriate, especially when the intent is to emphasize equivalence with the subject, even when plural.

The examples from the original source:

> Years of selective breeding have produced turkeys that are nothing but
>   cooking pouches with legs (Garrison Keillor, "With All the Trimmings,"
>   Time)
>
> Angels on horseback were nothing but oysters wrapped in thin rashers
>   of bacon, fried and served hot on buttered toast (Gail
>   Anderson-Dargatz, Cure for Death)

Nonetheless, the prevailing pattern is for *nothing but* and similar constructions
to get singular verbs, even when emphasizing plural entities.